# Wildcards for tag references of repositories in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I could not find any references to this topic: Is it possible to use some kind of wildcards in order to always get the latest (non-breaking) repository in a pipeline?

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: my_repo
    type: git
    name: myProject/repo
    ref: refs/tags/version-1.3.3  # something like version-1.3.* would be cool
```

Comment: You can add a tag called `1.3` that is progressively updated to the latest `1.3.x` release and point to that tag.

Comment: True, why not... let's wait a day or two - if no other suggestions appear, you may post it as answer ;)

Comment: Update: I think the solution to progressively update a tag (in this example `1.3`) is not a good idea, since the tags are considered as immutable and should not be changed. Imagine a coworker with a local clone, he would need to delete the tag and pull again.
Another option would be a `release/1.3` branch as example, and progressively change the branch.